# How to handle multiple correct outputs in neural networks

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I've been working on some basic neural networks. So far I only know of the feedforward, back-propagation types. I was wondering how one would calculate error when there are multiple correct outputs for a certain input.

Comment: Try asking on an AI dedicated forum.

Comment: Weight them, then select the top weighted one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, one of the basic assumptions of supervised machine learning is that there is only one correct output for a certain input vector. There are some exceptions, however, for instance, Elman network, where the output depends not only on the input, but also of the output on some previous inputs. Such networks are often used in working with time series. Would that be what you are wondering about? Or maybe you have some other applications on your mind?